# How to exploit Execution After Redirect vulnerability in PHP?

Tags: php, security, exploit

I read about the [EAR vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Execution_After_Redirect_%28EAR%29) in websites. But its hard to think of an exploit for EAR in PHP. Can anyone provide a specific example about how the attacker can exploit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the code below;

```
<?php

if (!$loggedin) {
  header('location: login.php');
}

echo 'You can only see this secret stuff if you are logged in!';
```

The echo'ed text is still returned - so *not* blindly obeying the `location` header will let you read the "secret message".

Also, I think this post belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The point here is that `header` sets an HTTP response header field that is only interpreted by the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply hank. How can I move this post to  http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you would have followed one link further to ["Fear the Ear"](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~bboe/public/pubs/fear-the-ear-ccs2011.pdf) you would have found:

> Listing 3: Example of an information leakage Execution After Redirect vulnerability in PHP:

```
$current_user = get_current_user ();
if (!$current_user ->is_admin())
{
    header("Location: /");
}
echo "Sensitive Information ";
```